Dataframe column-wise replace values above cutoff with max values below cutoff
I have a sample dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [10, 18, 30, 40],
    'B': [50, 20, 40, 6]
})

Given a cutoff number, say, 25, how to replace all values above the cutoff with max values below cutoff column wise?
A working solution:
import numpy as np
cutoff = 25
for col in df:
    ceiling = df[col][ df[col] <= cutoff ].max()
    df[col] = np.where(df[col] > cutoff, ceiling, df[col])

Which gives:
    A    B
0  10   20
1  18   20
2  18   20
3  18   6

My actual dataframe is much larger and therefore performance sensitive.

Can you share some testing data? I actually tested vectorized mask+clip vs your loop and this is quite similar but numpy (see my answer) is about 10x faster. I'd help to have a reference

you can just use pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5000, 20)) as a test case, and set cutoff as 0.8 for example.

that's similar to what I've done in my  benchmark, in this case my numpy approach should be ~10x faster

Use DataFrame.clip with get maximal value under cutoff with DataFrame.where and max:
cutoff = 25

out = df.clip(upper=df.where(df.le(cutoff)).max(), axis=1)
print (out)
    A   B
0  10  20
1  18  20
2  18  20
3  18   6

How it working:
print (df.le(cutoff))
       A      B
0   True  False
1   True   True
2  False  False
3  False   True

print (df.where(df.le(cutoff)))
      A     B
0  10.0   NaN
1  18.0  20.0
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   6.0

print (df.where(df.le(cutoff)).max())
A    18.0
B    20.0
dtype: float64


You can use a mask and clip:
cutoff = 25
df.clip(upper=df.mask(df.gt(cutoff)).max(), axis=1)

Or numpy broadcasting:
m = df.gt(cutoff)
df[m] = np.broadcast_to(np.nanmax(df.mask(m), axis=0), df.shape)

Output:
    A   B
0  10  20
1  18  20
2  18  20
3  18   6

Intermediates (pandas):
df.gt(cutoff)
       A      B
0  False   True
1  False  False
2   True   True
3   True  False

df.mask(df.gt(cutoff))
      A     B
0  10.0   NaN
1  18.0  20.0
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   6.0

df.mask(df.gt(cutoff)).max()
A    18.0
B    20.0
dtype: float64

Intermediates (numpy):
np.broadcast_to(np.nanmax(df.mask(df.gt(cutoff)), axis=0), df.shape)
array([[18, 20],
       [18, 20],
       [18, 20],
       [18, 20]])

timings:
# original approach
28.7 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# mask+clip
28.5 ms ± 785 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# numpy
3.37 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

